# How can I solve this system of linear equations?

Tags: r

I cannot find a complete answer to this question. I am attempting to solve a similar system of equations to this:

```
r_Aus <- 8.7 + r_Fra + r_Ser + r_USA
r_Fra <- 2.7 + r_Aus + r_Chi + r_Ser
r_USA <- 37 + r_Chi + r_Ven + r_Aus
r_Chi <- -29.7 + r_USA + r_Fra + r_Ven
r_Ser <- 2.7 + r_Ven + r_Aus + r_Fra
r_Ven <- -21.3 + r_Ser + r_USA + r_Chi
```

How could I solve for each country variable??

Comment: Have you tried `solve`?

Comment: @Psidom yes but I do not believe I am doing so correctly...

Comment: For the example you give, two lines of code to construct the coefficient matrix and then `solve` it gives the correct result: `a = matrix(-1, ncol = 4, nrow = 4); diag(a) <- 1; solve(a, c(10, 3, -7, -6))`

Comment: @Psidom This works! However, when I add another component (so that the matrix is not square) it does not work. Suggestions?

Comment: Overdetermined or underdetermined?

Comment: You have to make sure the equation has solution first of all.

Comment: @Bhas 6 equations, 6 unknowns. I will update the question with what I am actually trying to find -- Olympic games

Comment: I think your matrix rank is 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Preparation**

We first express your linear system in matrix form `A * x = b`. In case you are unclear of how to do this, have a read on [General forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#General_form). For your example, you can express it as:

```
## x = r_Aus, r_Chi, r_Fra, r_Ser, r_USA, r_Ven
  r_Aus         - r_Fra - r_Ser - r_USA         =  8.7
- r_Aus - r_Chi + r_Fra - r_Ser                 =  2.7
- r_Aus - r_Chi                 + r_USA - r_Ven =  37
        + r_Chi - r_Fra         - r_USA - r_Ven = -29.7
- r_Aus         - r_Fra + r_Ser         - r_Ven =  2.7
        - r_Chi         - r_Ser - r_USA + r_Ven = -21.3
```

then define coefficient matrix `A` and RHS vector `b`:

```
A <- matrix(c( 1,  0, -1, -1, -1,  0,
              -1, -1,  1, -1,  0,  0,
              -1, -1,  0,  0,  1, -1,
               0,  1, -1,  0, -1, -1,
              -1,  0, -1,  1,  0, -1,
               0, -1,  0, -1, -1,  1),
            nrow = 6, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)

b <- as.matrix(c(8.7, 2.7, 37, -29.7, 2.7, -21.3))
```

---

**Trying `solve()`**

Almost always, we think about `solve` first. But `solve()` is based on LU factorization, and requires a full rank coefficient matrix `A`; when `A` is found rank-deficient, LU factorization meets a 0 diagonal element and fails. Let's try your `A` and `b`:

```
solve(A, b)
#Error in solve.default(A, b) : 
#  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[6,6] = 0
```

`U[0,0] = 0` tells you, your `A` has only a rank of 5.

---

**A stable method: QR factorization**

QR factorization is known to be a very stable method. We can make use of `.lm.fit()` to do this:

```
x <- .lm.fit(A, b)
x$coef
# [1]   4.783333  -5.600000 -21.450000 -18.650000  40.866667   0.000000
x$rank
# [1] 5
```

Your system is of rank-5, so least square fitting is performed. The 6th value is `r_Ven` is constrained at 0, and none of your equations are exactly satisfied. `x$resi` gives you residuals, i.e., `b - A %*% x$beta`.

---

**Gaussian elimination**

To complete the picture, I have to mention Gaussian elimination. **In theory** this is the best approach, as you can determine whether:

1. there is a unique solution;
2. there is no solution;
3. there are infinite number of solutions

as well as solving the linear system.

There is a small R package `optR` around, but as I found out, it is not doing a perfect job.

```
#install.packages("optR")
library(optR)
```

`?optR` gives a full rank linear system as an example which works certainly fine (where simply using `solve(A, b)` would also work!). But for your system with rank-5, it gives:

```
optR(A, b, method="gauss")

call: 
optR.default(x = A, y = b, method = "gauss")

 Coefficients: 
           [,1]
[1,]   9.466667
[2,] -24.333333
[3,] -16.766667
[4,]  -4.600000
[5,]  22.133333
[6,]   0.000000
Warning messages:
1: In opt.matrix.reorder(A, tol) : Singular Matrix
2: In opt.matrix.reorder(A, tol) : Singular Matrix
```

Note the warning message that your linear system is rank-deficient. To understand what `optR` does in such case, compare `b` with

```
A %*% x$beta
#      [,1]
#[1,]   8.7
#[2,]   2.7
#[3,]  37.0
#[4,] -29.7
#[5,]   2.7
#[6,]   6.8
```

The first 5 equations are satisfied, except the 6th. So, `optR` abandoned your last equation to address rank-deficiency, instead of doing least square fitting.

Comment: Can you explain why you put what you did in the matrix please?

Comment: Or maybe do the same thing with my example so I have a better understanding?

Comment: Yes I could use some help with that please

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you for taking the time to do this. Would I interpret r_Ven as having a rating of 0.0? I should have clarified earlier but this is an adapted method from what has been used for other sporting rating systems: http://www.pro-football-reference.com/blog/?p=37

Comment: I appreciate the time you spent on this problem and the answer you gave was good but provided I do some other research to truly understand it myself. I left it open so that once I understood it I could assure its validity in answering the question and also give others to provide a more clear answer.